# Visual Studio 2010, using VB.NET. Intellisense does not recognize new property until I recompile

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have an ASP.NET VB.NET web project that references a VB.NET class library.

I add a new property to a class in the class library, then, from the web app, I expect to be able to use it immediately w/o errors and with full intellisense.

It used to work in 2008.

When I compile the class library, it becomes available but not until.

Was this nice feature taken away, perhaps in the interest of speed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's likely happening here is that the Class Library and ASP.Net applications are targeting different versions of the framework.  If they are using incompatible versions of the framework then VB.Net will treat it as a file reference instead of a project reference and would give you the behavior you're seeing.

Right click on the project, select the Appilication Tab and make sure that both have the same value selected for Target Framework.  That should fix the problem.

Comment: When opening the 2008 project in 2010, I was prompted if I wanted to update the app to Framework 4,. I expected that all libraries would be upgraded, too, but it only upgraded the web app, not the referenced project libraries. Thanks for pting this out to me.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2010 will officially launch on April 12, 2010. I'd say there's a good chance that problem will be fixed in it. Go see.

EDIT: corrected the date.

Comment: Where did you get the date of March 22?

Comment: Well, I did a Google search. Now that I did it again and looked a bit more close, it appears to have been postponed. See http://www.edsquared.com/2010/01/14/TFS+2010+And+Visual+Studio+2010+Launch+Date.aspx